# Deduce that every element $g$ of $SL_2(\mathbb R)$ may be expressed in the form $g=hk$ where $h\in H$ and $k$ is a rotation.

Tags: group-theory, mobius-transformation

> Let $G$ be $SL_2(\mathbb R)$ the group of real $2\times 2$ matrices of
>   determinant $1$, acting on $\mathbb C\cup \{\infty\}$ by Möbius transformations. Compute the orbit and and stabiliser of each
>   of $0,i,-i$.
>
> Compute the orbit of $i$ under the subgroup
>   $$H=\begin{Bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\0 & d \end{pmatrix}:a,b,d\in
>  \mathbb R, ad=1\end{Bmatrix}.$$ Deduce that every element $g$ of $G$
>   may be expressed in the form $g=hk$ where $h\in H$ and for some
>   $\theta \in \mathbb R$, $$k=\begin{pmatrix}\cos \theta & -\sin
>  \theta\\\sin \theta & \cos\theta \end{pmatrix}$$

I get the orbits in
$G$
and
$H$
as
$\{z\in \mathbb C:\Im(z)>0\}, \{z\in \mathbb C:\Im(z)=0\}, \{z\in \mathbb C:\Im(z)<0\}$.
I can kind of see where the result will come from but I can't quite get it out.

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and do the exercise in its abstract form. Suppose

- $G$ acts on a set $X$
- $H$ is a subgroup of $G$
- $H$ acts transitively on $X$
- $K$ is the stabilizer of a point of $X$

Use these hypotheses to prove $G=HK$, i.e. every $g\in G$ is expressible as $hk$.

Hint: Suppose $K$ is the stabilizer of $x$. Since $H$ acts transitively, every $g$ sends $x$ to a place that some $h\in H$ sends it to too, in which case you want to show $g$ and $h$ differ by an element of $K$.

In fact, we can go further: if we restrict to $H_0$, the subgroup of your $H$ with positive diagonal entries, then $H_0$ acts *regularly* on your $X$, in which case $H_0\cap K=1$, which means every $g\in G$ is *uniquely* expressible as $hk$ with $h\in H_0,k\in K$.

Note that $G=H_0K$ is equivalent to $G=KH_0$ (apply reciprocation to both sides) and the latter can be proved by showing for every $g\in G$ there is a $k\in K$ for which $k^{-1}g\in H_0$, which can be done by seeing that left-multiplying by rotation matrices simply rotates each column, and it will be possible to rotate the first column vector to be in the positive $x$-axis.

Moreoever, this $H_0$ of positive upper triangulars may be further decomposes as $AN$, where $A$ is comprised of diagonal matrices with positive entries and $N$ is comprised of unitriangulars. This gives the decomposition $G=KAN$, for which we know that the map $K\times A\times N\to G$ given by $(k,a,n)\mapsto kan$ is a diffeomorphism. This is called the [Iwasawa decomposition](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/SL(2,R).pdf) of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$.